# splitting data into columns

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a chunk of numbers in one row I need to split into multiple columns.

An example is:

```
P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000
```

The first three numbers are one category, followed by the next nine, so on and so forth. I am having trouble figuring out a way to split this into multiple columns or a data frame. I am new to R so I will do my best to keep up with the responses. Thank you!

Comment: is nchar() of your string always 52?

Comment: You can use `read.fwf` and specify the `widths`.  Is it following 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, etc?

Comment: His string is not consistent for : 3,9,3,9,3.... `P04 012000000 000 000000000 100 110121000 000 012000000 000 0`. His string is also not consistent for :3,9,9,9,9.... `P04 012000000 000000000 000100110 121000000 012000000 0000`

Comment: No, the number is not always 3,9,3,9. That was just an example. the string length for each variable is: 24,1,3,1, and so on. The first step is to split the numbers at the 25th number because that will divide it so I can split it into 4 parts (the 25th number refers to a table, listed as table 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Yes, nchar() is always 52.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is 24, 1, 3, 1 or different.  You can specify that in the `widths` in `read.fwf`

Comment: `read.fwf` is sometimes very slow, you may also try `readLines` to read the file and then `substring` to split the strings

Comment: I did the read.fwf, it split the data down the middle but it did so in the console. I am trying to re-write the data to be saved so I can re-call it in columns I can name. How do I do this?

Comment: @Idignatius Is the pattern 3,9,9,9,.... or 3,9,3,9...?

Comment: @Idignatius please check below answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern to extract is always `000 000000000 000000000 000000000 000000000 000000000 0000...` then here is a very old fashioned way of doing this in R.
Please note the pattern is 3,9,9,9,9,y where y being those strings that don't fit in 9 characters to make the column. Also note this can be done for strings over length 52.

```
x<-"P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000"
[1] "P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000"
```

The string here is `"P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000"` and you want to extract it in this way in different columns

`P04 012000000 000000000 000100110 121000000 00000`

```
library(stringr)

x<-"P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000"
Column1<-str_sub(x,1,3)
sub<-str_sub(x,4, nchar(x))
st<-1
en<-9
nchar(sub)
C<-as.character()
while (en!=nchar(sub)-(nchar(sub)%%9) )
{
  C<-cbind(C, str_sub(sub,st,en))
    st<-en+1
    en<-en+9
}
C<-cbind(C,str_sub(sub,en, nchar(sub)))
D<-data.frame(cbind(Column1,C))
D

Column1        V2        V3        V4        V5    V6
1     P04 012000000 000000000 000100110 121000000 00000
```